# Remotedesktop - monitor activity statistics - Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: remote-desktop, statistics

I have a Windows Server 2008 R2 setup with multiple users working on using remotedesktop. I'd like to get some statistics of theyr interaction with the system throughout the day. Like for example how many keystrokes were sent at what time or also interaction using the mouse or other ways of interaction. great would be some graph that shows during what time of the day there was heavy interaction with the system and when there was no - as well as when the user signed off and signed in.

Is there any tool to create such statistics?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about keystrokes, but there was a similar question about [RDP activity monitoring on ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/206085/are-there-any-rdp-activity-logs-windows-server-2008-r2).  The accepted answer contained the following:

A few options..

1. Basic windows logging using the policy setting "Audit Logon Events" should cover your needs.
2. You can also use a Remote Desktop Gateway and configure auditing that logs which users are accessing which internal resources via RDP. Some additional information is available here.
3. [SecureRDP](http://www.2x.com/securerdp/) has detailed logging that outputs to .CSV format. SecureRDP is now offered for free.

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool that is able to monitor user activity on remote desktop on the windows server 2008 R2. 
You can check some user activity reports here: https://www.syskit.com/features/user-activity-monitoring/

Basically the tool extract the data from the RDP protocol and it is able to show if the user was active or idle on the server, and for how long.

Please note: I work for the company behind this product. U can contact me directly if you need anything, if you thing the tool should be free let me know directly, I will see what I can do :-)